# Google scripts get address not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts

I'm trying to create an app that imports contacts and puts them in a spreadsheet, but I keep getting this error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getAddress" of undefined

This even happends from the sample code from the gscript website:

```
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('John Doe');
 var homeAddress = contacts[0].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
 Logger.log(homeAddress[0].getAddress());
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getAddress" of undefined
```

also get the same thing when trying to import phone numbers even though it imports names and id's

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that `homeAddress[0]` is undefined, which means that the method `getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS)` returned empty array, which means the contact does not have a Home Address listed. Add a check for such situation:

```
var homeAddress = contacts[0].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
if (homeAddress.length) {
  Logger.log(homeAddress[0].getAddress());
}
else {
  Logger.log('No home address found')
}
```

Comment: What if there isnt any labor though?

Comment: Label* I want to get any email thats there